# Компиляция java приложения

Tags: java

При компиляции выводит ошибку Error 2 opening pipe to PLUMB.EXE 
Парни я про PLUMB.EXE спрашиваю что такое эклипс я знаю!

Comment: PLUMB.EXE  - это что?

Comment: Я у вас хотел спросить!

Comment: случайно в качестве редактора не используется ли TextPad ?

Comment: да да он самый

Comment: редактор переустановить?

Comment: или переустановить, или компилировать с консоли.

Comment: или поставь эклипс =)

Comment: А что это за фаил?

Comment: эклипс - файл? ты когда на яве писать начал? вчера вечером?

Comment: эклипс? это отличный "редактор".
plumb.exe - это часть TextPad, который занимается перехватом консольного вывода компилятора (если я правильно понял)

Answer (score 1):

```
 javac HelloWorld.java
 java  HelloWorld
```

тогда тут и TextPad  не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Да плюньте вы на текст-пад. Кимпилируйте ant-ом. Заодно научитесь им пользоваться.

Comment: о, холиВар, пользуйтесь maven-ом

Comment: что бы скомпилировать один файл (как скорее всего нужно вопрошающему), заводим "монстров". Если комары мешают, так расстреливать их только баллистическими ракетами и никак не меньше.

Comment: @Gorets, какой холивар? Где вы тут разглядели его? <br />
@KoVadim речь о том, что это пойдёт на пользу. Потому что на практике программы не состоят из одного класса. А ещё, по сто раз выполнять rm, javac, java надоедает очень быстро.

Comment: на будущее, да, ant - это хорошо (либо любая другая система сборки). Но автору вопроса она не нужна, как минимум ещё с пол годика.